# wifi is not working after ubuntu installation and not show list of visible connections in hp laptops?

Tags: wireless

i am installing ubuntu so many times 14.4 and 16.04 ubuntu version in different hp model laptops but same problem occurs.Wi-fi not working and not scanning visible or available wi-fi.

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos